# How to run scripts from the control panel with a custom service?

Tags: groovy, liferay

Recently I tried to run a script from the control panel. The problem is that the script engine doesn't understand my custom service though I imported it.

```
"Unable to resolve class"
```

How can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this [PortletBeanLocatorUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/util/bean/PortletBeanLocatorUtil.html)

Example:

```
def ser = com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortletBeanLocatorUtil
       .locate("your-portlet-name-portlet",
        "com.example.yourclass.service.ItemLocalService")

def dq = ser.dynamicQuery()
```